# NGINX Proxy Server for Angular Development

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy

I'm developing a front end to one of our existing API's, and I am getting CORS erros while developing because origin is the page that  the web server that ships with Angular is for development is serving. But that's expected behavior, so usually I simply use a proxy config and work without a hitch, however now I am getting a error in the dependency that angular uses to create the proxy, namely `node-http-proxy`  [(found here)](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy).

I have determined that it is a bug they have with headers and nothing to do with my code (and I've been using that same solution many times befor), so in the mean while I thought I'd serve the app without the --proxy flag and setup a nginx proxy on my dev machine, however I'm havivng some trouble since I am a nginx noob.

this is what I have so far under my main config for nginx

```
server {  
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost:4200;
      location API/V6/ {  
                   proxy_pass https://XXXXXXX.com/API/V6;  
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;  
                   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
                   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;  
                   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
           }  
}
```

The angular dev server is running at :4200 and our endpoint is https://XXXXXXX.com/API/V6 (real url hidden for security reasons). so all in my http client I won't call `https://XXXXXXX.com/API/V6`, instead I just call `API/V6`, as I usually did when using my proxy setup in angular. Running this I cannot seem to reach to sever, just a dead call.

Comment: You are missing a leading `/`, try: `location /API/V6/`

Comment: tried that, no success